# Why am I not able to return None from Future

Tags: scala

Why does this code doesn't compile?

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global


scala> def fut:Future[Int] = {
     |
     |   val f1:Option[Int] = Future{ None }
     |    f1.map (x => {  //when f1 finishes, create another future
     |   println(x)
     |         x match {
     |    case Some(i) => {
     |            0 
     |          }
     |          case None => { 
     |             val f2 = Future{ 2 } 
     |             f2.map(x => 1) 
     |    }
     |        }
     |     })
     |  }
<console>:30: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[None.type]
 required: Option[Int]
         val f1:Option[Int] = Future{ None }
                                    ^
<console>:35: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : Some[A]
 required: Int
         case Some(i) => {
              ^
<console>:38: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : None.type
 required: Int
                case None => { //user doesn't exist. create the user in the database using another Future
                     ^
<console>:32: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Option[Any]
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[Int]
          f1.map (x => {  //when f1 finishes, create another future
                 ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val f1:Option[Int] = Future{ None }
```

A `Future` is not an `Option`. You probably meant

```
val f1: Future[Option[Int]] = Future.successful(None)
```

---

```
case Some(_) => 0
case None => aFuture
```

This won't work, either. You have to return a `Future[Int]` in both branches. That also implies `flatMap` instead of `map` on `f1`

---

In summary

```
def fut: Future[Int] = {

    val f1: Future[Option[Int]] = Future.successful(None)

    f1.flatMap(x => { //when f1 finishes, create another future
      x match {
        case Some(i) => {
          Future.successful(0)
        }
        case None => {
          val f2 = Future.successful(2)
          f2.map(x => 1)
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: My understanding is that the last statement in a Future{...} becomes the return value of the Future. So should `None` be returned which is a valid value for `f1`. Isn't that the case?

Comment: Not if you declare `f1` to be an `Option[Int]`. `f1` is still a `Future[Option[Int]]` (the Option wrapped into a Future).

Comment: got it. I should have declared `f1` as `Future[Option[Int]]`